# multiple sub plots with for looping

Tags: python, subplot

Alright so i want to plot 421 in a 6x4 sub plot and i want this to create a new image after every 24th image. I've tried somethings before but it ends up giving normal 421 plots one below the other

```
for i in range(0,421):
a = df.iloc[i:i+1]
x = np.concatenate([a['t11_arms_number_a31_1_weighted_fraction'],a['t11_arms_number_a32_2_weighted_fraction'],a['t11_arms_number_a33_3_weighted_fraction'],a['t11_arms_number_a34_4_weighted_fraction'],a['t11_arms_number_a36_more_than_4_weighted_fraction'],a['t11_arms_number_a37_cant_tell_weighted_fraction']])
y = np.linspace(1,6,6)
plt.plot(y,x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call plt.show() it shows a plot. If you only want to show plots of groups of 24 subplots you simply call plt.show() once every 24 steps. I just plotted some lines in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(0,421):
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    plt.plot(x,x+i)
    if(i%24 == 0):
        plt.show()
```